# A function which is given an array containing objects defining people’s names and ages

Tags: javascript

Return: a string formatted as a list of names and age groups separated by commas except for the last two names, which should be separated by an ampersand.

The age group is broken down such that:

- For ages under 16 they are considered a ‘kid’
- For ages between 16 and 59 (inclusive) they are considered an ‘adult’
- For anything higher they are considered a ‘senior’

For example:

```
listPeople([{
    name: 'Bart',
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Lisa',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Maggie',
    age: 62
  }
]);
```

Returns:

Bart the kid, Lisa the adult & Maggie the senior

```
function listPeople(people) {
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    str += people[i].name;
    str += people[i].age;
    if(people[i].age <= 10 || people[i].age >= 20) {
      return people[i].name + "the kid " + people[i].age + "the adult " + "& " + people[i].age + "the senior";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `what I'm I doing wrong` You don't have anything in the function. Might be part of the problem

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the code wrote, do you mind taking a look and telling me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Currently, the input is invalid because it's not using straight quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getLabel(age) {
      return age < 16
        ? ' the kid'
        : (age < 60 ? ' the adult' : ' the senior')
    }

    function listPeople(arr) {
      const formattedString = arr.reduce((acc, person, index) => {
        acc = acc.concat(person.name).concat(getLabel(person.age));
        acc = index !== arr.length - 1
          ? (index >= arr.length-2  ? acc.concat(' & ') : acc.concat(', '))
          : acc;
        return acc;
      }, '');
      return formattedString;
    }

    listPeople([{
        name: 'Bart',
        age: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 20
      },
      {
        name: 'Maggie',
        age: 62
      }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code isn't testing for the conditions given at all. You need to separate out the last person in the array from the rest. Iterate over the first people and join with a comma, then do the same process for the last person, but join with a `&` instead of a comma.

Because you need to perform the same transformation on each person, try defining a function to turn the person into the properly formatted string, and then send each person through that function and join/concatenate as needed:

```js
function personToString(person) {
  if (person.age < 16) return person.name + ' the kid';
  if (person.age > 59) return person.name + ' the senior';
  return person.name + ' the adult';
}

function listPeople(people) {
  const allButLastPeople = people.slice(0, people.length - 1);
  const lastPerson = people[people.length - 1];

  const firstString = allButLastPeople.map(personToString).join(', ');
  const lastString = personToString(lastPerson);
  console.log(firstString + ' & ' + lastString);
}

listPeople([{name:'Bart',age:10},{name:'Lisa',age:20},{name:'Maggie',age:62}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I added comments in code):

```js
var l = listPeople([{
    name: 'Bart',
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Lisa',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Maggie',
    age: 62
  }
]);

console.log(l);

function listPeople(people) {
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    //Add the person's name
    str += people[i].name;

    //Add the age designation
    if (people[i].age < 16)
      str += " the kid";
    else if (people[i].age < 60)
      str += " the adult";
    else
      str += " the senior";

    //Add the separator
    if (i < people.length - 2)
      str += ", ";
    else if (i == people.length - 2)
      str += " & ";
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate the help